# Verbatim HTML code chunk in Slidify

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown, slidify

Using R, Rmarkdown and slidify to create a presentation about html templates in shiny.  Obviously this requires me to show examples of html templates.  I'm trying to put the following verbatim html chunk into a markdown code chunk in one of my slidify slides:

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{ headContent() }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      {{ button }}
      {{ slider }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, after rendering in slidify, the following html is displayed on my slide:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I get slidify to display the raw html verbatim without trying to interpret the mustache templates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one use a literal {{ in a Mustache template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042926/how-does-one-use-a-literal-in-a-mustache-template)

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/35441138/866026